# How to enable On-Screen-Keyboard for Flutter linux desktop

Tags: linux, flutter, on-screen-keyboard, flutter-desktop

I have developed a Desktop App for Linux with Flutter.

My Flutter Version is: Channel dev, 2.6.0-0.0.pre, on Ubuntu 21.04 5.11.0-1015-raspi with VS Code Version 1.56.2.

Flutter doctor did not find an issue.

Since i want to use this app via touchscreen and i have to input some text, i need the onscreen keyboard to appear. I have activated it in the accessibility settings.
When i'm clicking on a text field, the onscreen keyboard isn't displayed. Trying it with e.g. Firefox its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the dart repository there are [several cases](https://pub.dev/packages?q=virtual_keyboard), in my specific case the one I used was: "[new_virtual_keyboard](https://pub.dev/packages/new_virtual_keyboard)" package.